# Windows phone 8.1 Access Violation while navigating to new view

Tags: crash, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross, access-violation

I am getting a access violation issue in windows phone 8.1 app when running on device without any stack trace. I found an answer, to call dispatcher to navigate but I don't know how to do it with mvvmcross. Please help me.

[Access Violation cause and solution from codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/899026/Access-Violation-Crash-on-Windows-Phone-Devices)

Everything seems good in my code maybe it's causing inside ShowViewModel Method. Please help me.

```
Select click enter 14:24:56.2863139  
mvx:Diagnostic:  5.99 Showing ViewModel PlayMantraViewModel 
VM ctor enter 14:24:56.5572456  
VM ctor leave 14:24:56.5572456 
VM Init enter 14:24:56.5728871 
VM init leave 14:24:56.5885270 
appstate:Active 
Select click leave 14:24:56.6041698   
The program '[4028] Japam.WinPhone.exe' has exited with code
-1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I have total 3 views, navigating to another view works fine.

```
 ShowViewModel<PlayMantraViewModel>(new { mid = m.MantraID });
```

This what I call in the view model

Comment: Do you maybe have some managed resources that have not been cleaned up in the View/ViewModel you are navigating away from?

Comment: @Cheesebaron no because it navigates fine to another view, one view is to record audio and another one to play recorded audio with a background task. Recoding view works fine, but not playing view. Both works in emulator though.

Comment: Just because it navigates fine between the other views, doesn't magically mean you don't have to clean up after yourself in others. What triggers me here is that you are recording audio, you probably didn't clean that up properly and it fails when navigating away from it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron it's navigating fine from record view, without even going to record view the app first installed and navigating to play crashes the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, I need to use dispatcher

```
  this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
                ViewModel.MantraSelectedCommand.Execute(e.ClickedItem);
            });
```

This worked well.